# Pattern searching in excel file and get row ID python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am quite new to python, pandas. I am trying to read a csv file using pandas, but I am getting a csv parse error. That is my csv top pattern, See this (Cannot display image, please refer link).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIBoj.jpg

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,,,,,,,
                                                     Data Records,,,,,,,
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,,,,,,,
ABC : - xxxxxxxxxxx,,,,,,,
Type :- xxxxxxxxxxx,,,,,,,
Date :- xxxxxxxxxx,,,,,,,
Till Date :- xxxxxxxxxx,,,,,,,
Report Index :- xxxxxxxxxx,,,,,,,
Report Date :- 01-Jul-2017 11:18:41 AM,,,,,,,
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,,,,,,,
A PARTY, B PARTY, DATE, TIME, DURATION, ID, ID_A, TYPE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,,,,,,,
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:51:54,1,123456788889999, -, ZXC
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:52:06,1,123456788889999, -, QWE
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:52:11,1,123456788889999, -, RRR
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:52:12,1,123456788889999, -, BGF
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:52:25,1,123456788889999, -, OOO
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:53:23,1,123456788889999, -, BGF
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:54:00,1,123456788889999, -, NBG
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:54:38,1,123456788889999, -, BGFD
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 11:54:39,1,123456788889999, -, OIU
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 12:03:14,1,123456788889999, -, BGF
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 12:07:43,1,123456788889999, -, GGG
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 12:11:53,1,123456788889555, -, VVVV
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 12:13:12,1,123456788889555, -, VVVV
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 12:13:12,1,123456788889555, -, VVVV
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 12:13:44,1,123456788889555, -, VVVV
XXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX, 26-JAN-2017, 12:13:44,1,123456788889555, -, VVVV
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
Note :- This is a System generated Report.,,,,,,,
```

Above shared text is edited, my original file has 1000+ rows.

And error is -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module><br>
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)<br>
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)<br>
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)<br>
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)<br>
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read<br>
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory<br>
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 945, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows<br>
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows<br>
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error<br>
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 13
```

When I skip rows 12, it works perfectly fine. So, before reading this file I want to search for '---' pattern and get row ID, then I can skip rows while reading with 'read_csv' function.

```
import pandas as pd 
ff = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
ff
```

Here is my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the first 15 or so lines of your csv file?

Comment: Please post the contents of the file, instead of the screenshot from a spreadsheet application. Also, please provide the code that gives you the error: it's not possible to give a solution without knowing the problem :-)

Comment: Question edited, added python code.

Answer (score 0):

I got no error :

```
python.exe temp.py
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4       Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6 Unnamed: 7
0                                                 ...                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
1   ----------------------------------------------...                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
2                                 ABC : - xxxxxxxxxxx                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
3                                 Type :- xxxxxxxxxxx                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
4                                  Date :- xxxxxxxxxx                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
5                             Till Date :- xxxxxxxxxx                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
6                          Report Index :- xxxxxxxxxx                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
7              Report Date :- 01-Jul-2017 11:18:41 AM                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
8   ----------------------------------------------...                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
9                                             A PARTY                                                                                                    B PARTY          DATE       TIME   DURATION               ID       ID_A       TYPE
10  ----------------------------------------------...                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
11                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:51:54          1  123456788889999          -        ZXC
12                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:52:06          1  123456788889999          -        QWE
13                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:52:11          1  123456788889999          -        RRR
14                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:52:12          1  123456788889999          -        BGF
15                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:52:25          1  123456788889999          -        OOO
16                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:53:23          1  123456788889999          -        BGF
17                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:54:00          1  123456788889999          -        NBG
18                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:54:38          1  123456788889999          -       BGFD
19                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   11:54:39          1  123456788889999          -        OIU
20                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   12:03:14          1  123456788889999          -        BGF
21                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   12:07:43          1  123456788889999          -        GGG
22                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   12:11:53          1  123456788889555          -       VVVV
23                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   12:13:12          1  123456788889555          -       VVVV
24                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   12:13:12          1  123456788889555          -       VVVV
25                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   12:13:44          1  123456788889555          -       VVVV
26                                           XXXXXXXX                                                                                                   XXXXXXXX   26-JAN-2017   12:13:44          1  123456788889555          -       VVVV
27                                                NaN                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
28                                                NaN                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
29                                                NaN                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN
30         Note :- This is a System generated Report.                                                                                                        NaN           NaN        NaN        NaN              NaN        NaN        NaN

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My settings are Python 3.6.5 and

[image: Modules and their version]

Comment: I have python 2.7.12

Comment: As I stated in my question, this is edited csv text, surprisingly it is not throwing any error but the original file is, that file I cannot share but if I skip 10 rows (As per your result), the original file works perfectly.
Basically, Row 10 is the header and row 11-26 is data, which I want to extract.

Comment: Sorry! Row 9 is the header for me.